# Dual monitors spontaneously changes to single monitor at random intervals

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with a GeForce 1050 Ti graphics card. I have two Iiyama 24" ProLite 824 83HS monitors, one plugged directly into the DisplayPort socket on the graphics card; the other plugged into a HDMI to VGA convertor, which is plugged into the HDMI socket on the graphics card.

I have Display Mode set up (in Devices > Screen Display) as Join Displays, with both displays set up in Landscape at 1920 x 1080, at 100% scale. The two displays are side by side.

This works smoothly and well, most of the time. Every so often, at variable intervals (from a couple of minutes to many hours), both screens blank for 10 seconds or so, both screens become visible again for a couple of seconds (but the mouse pointer appears not to be movable), both screens go dark again for 10 seconds or so - and then only the primary monitor comes on, and Screen Display now shows the Display Mode as Single Display. This is not associated with the use of any particular software, as far as I have been able to tell.

Clicking "Join Displays" in Display Mode works fine, and the second monitor is turned on again with the usual "Revert Settings / Keep Changes" option offered. But I would really like not to have to keep resetting the Display Mode to my preferred option at random intervals.

I can't find a similar problem described in this or similar forums. Does anyone recognise this behaviour? Is there a system log I should be looking at to see what causes the unexpected change in Display Mode?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: All I can think of is if you are using Wayland switch to xrandr. If you are using Xrandr switch to Wayland. If that doesn't work then if you are using Unity switch to Gnome and if you are using Gnome switch to Unity. Hopefully someone posts an answer!

Comment: The display settings in Ubuntu aren't remembering anything. It's ridiculous, the posts here have been nonstop (and most of them, like this one, without answers). I really wish they'd fix their UX bugs. Several people have commented about Wayland vs `gdm3` but this is the first time I've seen someone say "If you are using Xrandr switch to Wayland." If the problem is ubuntu-desktop maybe we should all switch to Mate and be done?